# I am trying to make a joptionpane with many options that once clicked changes the skin of the player

Tags: java, character, joptionpane

So I have been working on player customization for a while now and JOptionPanes completely confuse me. I tried making a basic one which works but I have no clue how to make a JOptionPane change a variable in the game. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: can you do it without joptionpane ?

Comment: Start with [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html).  The basic premises is, you prompt the user with a series of options and based on the return value, which is typically the `int` value representing the index of the option array the user selected, you make your decisions

Comment: sorry its taking me so long to respond

Comment: I guess I could do it without a Joptionpane I like the premiss of what your saying